Flink StateFun - Removing an ingress and restoring from snapshot
Scenario is this:

We have a live event driven application run on Flink Statefun (on AWS
Managed Flink). The application has a number of ingresses
We develop the application and decide to remove a Kinesis ingress.
We stop the running Flink application, snapshot is taken.
On release of the revised code we need to restore from a snapshot taken when we stopped the application
Flink fails to start as the snapshot is expecting the ingress to exist

Is there any best practice to handling this kind of change - and maintaining state / snapshot in the parts of the application which have not changed?
